# Did the eight-episode miniseries (The Rook) end in a cliffhanger?

Tags: ending, the-rook

I have an opportunity to watch the miniseries, *The Rook*. But before I do, I would like to know if it ended in a cliffhanger.  Does anyone know?

Please no spoilers.

From Wikipedia:

> “The Rook is an American television series, loosely based on the novel of the same name by Daniel O'Malley, and originally adapted by Stephenie Meyer. It was ordered direct-to-series at Starz in July 2017.”

Comment: Not exactly but there were a lot of unanswered questions that might make you feel unfulfilled. They just didn't stick the landing.

Comment: Let me know if it's any good; is it worth 7 hours of my life to watch? ;)  I worked on that but had completely forgotten about it until I saw this question.

Comment: I wouldn't go out of my way. It has an interesting premise but I think they left a lot to resolve for proper satisfaction. No second season seems to agree.